# Windows boot cannot find windows 10 partition on Ubuntu dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10

The title is my theory of what happened, but I'm not certain: I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but while I am now able to boot Ubuntu without any issue, I am not longer able to boot Windows 10.

When selecting a boot in the BIOS settings, I do see the Windows 10 boot, in addition to the Ubuntu boot.

[image]

But when I select Windows 10, the following screen displays "Preparing Automatic Repair".

[image]

And from there it leads me to a blue screen with the main option being "Exit and go to Windows 10". But when I click that, the computer reboots and returns me to the boot selection screen.

[image]

I am almost sure that the Windows 10 partition is still there and was not formatted, but it seems like the Windows 10 boot isn't able to find or access it.

Any idea how I can fix this and properly boot Windows 10?

Comment: Was the Ubuntu install in UEFI mode_

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest :/

Comment: There most likely lies the problem.

Comment: how could I fix it then?

Comment: It's not that. If Ubuntu was installed in legacy mode it wouldn't have detected the other OSes EFI entries. Now, dear @krimo33, when installing OSes being "almost sure" is not good enough and not having backups is asking for trouble. OS and software can always be reinstalled but it only takes a small error to have those import personal files gone forever. Next, here's what you should try before anything else:

Comment: Open UEFI > Boot (NOT the Grub menu) and change the boot order to "Windows" in order to boot it directly. If it boots properly then immediately disable Fast Startup, a Windows hibernation feature), install any pending updates and reboot (Windows) as many times as it needs for the updates installation. Then shutdown and in the next power up again open UEFI > Boot and change it back to "Ubuntu" (Grub), boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. All your OSes should now boot correctly from Grub. **If Windows can't boot directly then you need Windows installation media to repair or reinstall it**.